# Installation did not succeed for android studio app

Tags: java, kotlin, installation, field

Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1153567129.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #197): com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present'

I'v tryed the ¨android exported true¨ for all my activites but it doesn't work so  if there is someone who can help it would be great
thank you;

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code of your manifest.

Comment: i can't stackoverflow shows that there is error in the code but there is nothing i can fixe. if thee is something else i can do?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean. I’ve never had any problems pasting text into a StackOverflow question. StackOverflow doesn’t check your code.

Comment: i make a new publish please check this link it contain my manifest code thnk you ¨ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74670623/installation-did-not-succeed-for-my-application-on-android-studio ¨¨