# installation did not succeed for my application on android studio

Tags: java, android, installation, new-operator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.video.maker1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.video.maker1.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/theme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-9731420309932281~3771749504" />

<!--        <activity-->
<!--            android:name="com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity"-->
<!--            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />-->

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">


        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.ImagePickerActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.SwapImageActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.SelectFrameActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.VideoPlayerActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.SongGalleryActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.VideoThemeActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service android:name="com.video.maker1.theme.service.ServiceAnim" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.MyVideo"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.VideoMakerActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.PrivacyActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        <activity android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.VideoTrimActivity" />


        <activity
            android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.VideoEditorActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.LibraryActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.SaveVideoFileActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity android:name="com.video.maker1.activity.VideoListActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.infiapp.imagelibrary.editimage.EditImageActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is my manifest code when i try to install my app on the emulator it shows me this error
^^The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED^^

i'hv tryed evrything that i know but it still showing me the same error
as you see i have tried the ^^android exported true commnd on all my activity but it doesn't work.

Comment: Few things to test:
1. uninstall and then try to install
2. Check the merged manifest
3. Clean the build and try rebuilding.

Comment: In the future, please don’t open duplicate questions. You can edit your existing question to add information. Is this the *complete* error message? Usually it gives you a hint about what exactly the problem is.